# Generating NSManagedObjectSubclass Automatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I see that Xcode properly add these methods on Business.m

```
- (void)addDistrictsObjectDistrict *)value {
NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"Districts" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"Districts"] addObject:value];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"Districts" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
[changedObjects release];
}
```

Unfortunately xcode do not add

(void)addDistrictsObjectDistrict *)value;

On Business.h

In other words the method is not exactly advertised to others.

Why?

I got compilerwarning when I tried to use function addDistrictsObject

Also I do not want to change either Business.h or Business.m The xdatamodel will still change a lot.

So what should I do?

Any way to avoid compiler warning? How should I use addObject without compiler warning using only generated code? Any category solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your data model is going to change a lot, you might want to use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your class files instead of the Xcode tool.

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but will check that out.